# react component rendering after state change working in delay

Tags: reactjs

I have those 2 components

FormComponent

```
const FormComponent = (props) => {
//keep the current step in the component state
const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(props.step);
const [componentData, setComponentData] = useState(null);
const [componentQuestions, setQuestions] = useState(null);
const [errors, setErrors] = useState();

const updateUserResponse = props.updateUserResponse;
const renderStepsTracker = props.renderStepsTracker;

/**
 * Get the component content after mount
 */
useEffect(() => {
    if (componentData) {
        setQustionsData(componentData);
    }
    //fire if componentData has changed or error object is changed
}, [errors,componentData]);

/**
 * Get the component content after mount
 */
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentStep && !componentData) {
        let stepData = currentStep.stepdata;

        stepData.update = getUpdateTime();

        setComponentData(stepData);
    }
});

/**
 * Get the current time in milliseconds
 */
const getUpdateTime = () => {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();

    return n
}

/**
 * Extract the questions from the step object and 
 * set the state accordingly
 */
const setQustionsData = (stepData) => {
    let questions = stepData.questions;

    //assign a react component to each question
    questions.map((question, key) => {
        const component = getComponent(question);
        const question_id = question.question_id;

        questions[key].component = component;
        questions[key].error = (null != errors && 'undefined' !== typeof errors[question_id]) ? errors[question_id] : '';

    })

    setQuestions(questions);
}

/**
 * a callback function to validate the current form
 * @param {object} step 
 */
const validateForm = (step) => {
    const formErrors = props.validateForm(step);

    setErrors(formErrors)
}

/**
 * Render the form
 */
const renderForm = () => {
    return null !== componentQuestions ? (
        <>
            <div className="row full-height">
                <div className="column">
                    <div className="form-wrapper">
                        <div className="questions">
                            {componentQuestions.map(question => {
                                return (
                                    <>
                                        {question.component}
                                    </>
                                )
                            })}
                        </div>
                        <NextStepButton
                            step={currentStep}
                            nextStepCallback={props.jumpToStep}
                            validateForm={validateForm}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    ) : ''
}

/**
 * Render the image in case it exists
 */
const renderImage = () => {
    return (
        <div className="full-height">
            <img className="full-height-image" src={componentData.image} alt="" />
        </div>
    )
}

/**
 * Get the question component
 */
const getComponent = (question) => {
    switch (question.question_type) {
        case "text":
            return (
                <div className="field-wrap">
                    <label>
                        <span className="question-label">{question.question_label}</span>
                        <span className="question-title">{question.question_title}</span>

                        <input type="text"
                            name={question.question_id}
                            onChange={updateUserResponse}
                            required={question.required}
                        />
                        {question.error ?
                            <span className={"error-message " + question.error.reason}>{question.error_message}</span>
                            : ''}

                    </label>
                </div>
            )
    }
}

return (
    componentData ?
        <>
            <div className="row full-height expanded">
                {componentData.image ?
                    <div className="column full-height col-collapse image-wrap">
                        {renderImage()}
                    </div>
                    : ''}
                <div className="column full-height questions-container">
                    {renderStepsTracker()}
                    {renderForm()}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
        : ''
)} enter code hereexport default FormComponent
```

**

- NextStepButton

**

```
    const NextStepButton = (props) => {

    const step = props.step
    const validateForm = props.validateForm

    return props.step.nextButtonText ? (
        <span className="next-step-button" onClick={() => { 
            validateForm( step )
         }}>
            {step.nextButtonText}
        </span>
    ) : ''
}

export default NextStepButton
```

When the user clicks on the next step the form is validated and returns an array of errors,
The array of errors is set to the component state and then supposed to display the error

For some reason the error appears only after the user clicks 3 times on the next step button

Why is that ?

EDIT
this is the main component that contains the global form validation

```
const MainContainer = () => {

    //set state variables
    const [nextButtonText, setNextButtonText] = useState()
    const [previousButtonText, setPreviousButtonText] = useState()
    const [backButtonCls, setBackButtonCls] = useState()
    const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState()
    const [stepsData, setStepsData] = useState()
    const [currentStepNum, setCurrentStepNum] = useState(null)
    const [classNames, setclassNames] = useState(null)
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({})

    //set refrence for callbacks that use this component state
    const ref = useRef({
        stepsData: stepsData,
        currentStep: currentStep
    })

    /**
     * On Initial state
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!stepsData) {
            getStepsData().then((response) => {
                initProcess(response)
            })
        }
    })

    /**
     * Init the process after getting data from the server
     */
    const initProcess = (response) => {

        const steps = setStepsComponents(response.data.steps)
        const initialStep = steps[0];
        ref.current.stepsData = steps

        setStepsData(steps)
        setStep(initialStep, 1)
    }

    /**
     * Form submission callback
     * Loop over step questions and check for the appropriate userdata
     */
    const validateForm = (submittedStep) => {
        let errors = {}; 
        if ('null' !== typeof submittedStep.stepdata.questions) {
            const questions = submittedStep.stepdata.questions

            questions.map((question, key) => {
                const question_name = question.question_id

                //if there is an error add it to the questions collection
                if (question.required && !userData[question_name]) {
                    errors[question.question_id] = {
                        reason : 'required'
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        if (errors) {
            return errors
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Capture user settings on change
     */
    const updateUserResponse = (event) => {
        userData[event.target.name] = event.target.value;

        setUserData(userData)
    }

    /**
     * Set the appropriate step component
     * @param {OBJECT} steps 
     */
    const setStepsComponents = (steps) => {
        steps.map((step, key) => {
            switch (steps[key]['component']) {
                case "onboarding":
                    steps[key]['component'] = <Onboarding step={step} setUserData />
                    break;
                case "questions":
                    steps[key]['component'] = <FormComponent
                        step={step}
                        renderStepsTracker={renderStepsTracker}
                        updateUserResponse={updateUserResponse}
                        validateForm={validateForm}
                    />
                    break;
            }
        })

        return steps
    }

    /**
     * Callback function that creates the steps tracker on each component
     */
    const renderStepsTracker = () => {

        return ref.current.stepsData ? (
            <>
                <div className="stepsTracker">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="column">
                            <div className="stepsTrackerWrap">
                                {ref.current.stepsData.map((step, key) => {
                                    const activeClass = ref.current.currentStep === key ? "active" : ""
                                    return key > 0 ? (
                                        <>
                                            <div className={"stepTracker " + activeClass}>
                                                <div className="stepTrackerImage">
                                                    <img src={step.icon} alt="" />
                                                </div>
                                                <label>{step.stepdata.title}</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="stepSpacer"></div>
                                        </>
                                    ) : ''
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        ) : ''
    }
    /**
     * Render the steps component if data is available
     */
    const renderSteps = () => {
        return stepsData ? (
            <StepZilla
                steps={stepsData}
                onStepChange={onstepChange}
                nextButtonText={nextButtonText}
                showSteps={false}
                backButtonText={previousButtonText}
                backButtonCls={backButtonCls}
            />
        ) : ''
    }

    /**
     * Set the data for the current step
     * @param {object} step 
     */
    const setStep = (step, stepNum) => {
        setNextButtonText(step.showNextButton ? step.nextButtonText : true)
        setPreviousButtonText(step.previousButtonText)
        setBackButtonCls(step.backButtonCls)
        setCurrentStep(step)

        setCurrentStepNum(stepNum)

        ref.current.currentStep = stepNum

        //add bottom padding in case the next button appears
        if (step.showNextButton) {
            setclassNames('padding')
        } else {
            setclassNames(' ')
        }
    }

    /**
     * Perform actions when step is changed
     * @param {step} step 
     */
    const onstepChange = (stepNum) => {
        if ('undefined' === typeof stepNum) {
            stepNum = '0';
        }

        setCurrentStepNum(stepNum)

        const nextStep = stepsData[stepNum];
        setStep(nextStep, stepNum)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className={'step-progress ' + classNames}>
                {renderSteps()}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default MainContainer
```

Comment: What is `props.validateForm`? Where is `validateForm` passed as a prop to `FormComponent`? Can you update your question to include all relevant code?

Comment: Updated the main container component

Comment: Can you recreate it in sandbox?

Comment: Agreed, there is too much code to sift through and track without understanding how it's all supposed to fit together and work. A *running* codesandbox would be great. I've managed to step through the code manually up to `submittedStep.stepdata.questions` in `validateForm`. If `'null' !== typeof submittedStep.stepdata.questions` condition always evaluates `false` then you *always* return an empty (`{}`) error object back to the form. (*You always return an error object regardless, actually*) Perhaps you meant to check `if (Object.keys(errors).length) return errors`.

Comment: Here it is https://icv2h.csb.app/ just click the next button and after that click twice on the the text "Click here to validate" you will notice that the error appears only after the second click

Comment: Your code seems unnecessarily convoluted, and honestly it's an anti-pattern to store "components"/"JSX" in react state, i.e. the `componentQuestions`. I tested this by directly rendering `showError(question.question_id)` in `renderForm` instead of `question.component` and the error "test" displays after the first click of "Click here to validate" (formComponent:90). It seems when you are setting the question data and getting the component the component's error is a render cycle behind (likely due to the overly complex state updates.

Comment: Thanks i have unconvoluted the sturcture and removed the components from the state, it is now working!

Comment: Great. Good luck from there. :)